# "AnalyticsReceiver is not registered or is disabled."

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I have just started upgrading my Android app from the old, deprecated, Analytics SDK to v4. I followed the documentation and as far as I can tell I did everything right.

On my device (which has Google Play Services installed) data seems to be sent just fine.

What worries me is that in the logs I see this message every time my app starts; `AnalyticsService not registered in the app manifest. Hits might not be delivered reliably. See http://goo.gl/8Rd3yj for instructions.` -- And of course, I'd prefer to get accurate statistics.

The message seems quite clear; "Add this stuff to your `AndroidManifext.xml` file". The problem is that it's already there...

This is in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file, inside the `application` tag, beneath the `activity` and `service` tags that are required by the rest of my app;

```
    <!-- Google Analytics -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
```

Is this a known issue? Am I missing something else?

I went for the "extend `Application` and have the tracker as a static property" approach that is also used in the [Getting Started part of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#tracking-methods).

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. Did you manage to get it working?

Comment: Nope, warning is still there.

Comment: @RobinJ still no luck?

Comment: @Marky17 Nope. I'm just ignoring the issue for now. Statistics are not *that* important to me, although it would still be nice to get (mostly) accurate ones if possible.

Comment: Same issue here, I'm using the latest version and the code seems to be fine but I'm still getting the warning. And I don't seem to be able to get any further logs from any of my events. Analytics is working fine, it's just the warning.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and fixed it with

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0'
```

whereas before I was using a beta version.

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore the warning and don't need to add receiver/service if you only target play-service enabled devices. Check https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/dispatch#manual for details.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest version of Google Play Services library in your build.gradle file.

Or you can setup dependency on any version:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'`

Comment: It's on the latest version.